# How to Override /sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml under Customer Sales Order View Section in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to Override `/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` under Customer Sales Order View Section (My Account Page) from my custom module.

I have created following 3 files.

`/app/code/local/Revered/Expdlvrydate/etc/config.xml`

---

```
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Revered_Expdlvrydate>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Revered_Expdlvrydate>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <revered>
                        <file>revered.xml</file>
                    </revered>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

---

`/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/revered/revered.xml`

---

```
    <layout>
        <sales_order_view translate="label">
            <reference name="my.account.wrapper"> 
                <action method="addItemRender">
                    <type>default</type>
                    <block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block>
                    <template>revered/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <action method="addItemRender">
                    <type>grouped</type>
                    <block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block>
                    <template>revered/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </reference> 
        </sales_order_view>
    </layout>
```

---

`/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/revered/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml`

---

### I used this file same as default

Thanks in Advance,
Ziya

Comment: Anyone is available for this help?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got fixed it myself:

**My config file is**

```
/app/code/local/Revered/Expdlvrydate/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Revered_Expdlvrydate>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Revered_Expdlvrydate>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <expdlvrydate_layout module="Expdlvrydate">
                    <file>expdlvrydate.xml</file>
                </expdlvrydate_layout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**My layout file is**

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/expdlvrydate.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_items">
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>default</type>
                <block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block>
                <template>revered/expdlvrydate/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

**My phtml file is**

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/revered/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

Added following code below item options

```
<?php if ($_item = $this->getItem()): ?>
        <?php if ( $_item->getEdeliverydate() != NULL):?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml('Expected Delivery Date') ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->formatDate($_item->getEdeliverydate(), 'long'); ?></dd>
        </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```